# Having trouble understanding the solution of $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}+2\frac{dy}{dx}+\lambda y=0,$ $y(0)=y(1)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

Good day.

I was working on this problem from my lecture notes.

###### "Find eigenvalues and corresponding eigenfunctions
for the BVP

#### $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}+2\frac{dy}{dx}+\lambda y=0,$
$y(0)=y(1)=1$

###### and verify their orthogonality by direct calculation"

There's also a solution provided, which I've followed along with. Though solving the whole exercise is the end goal, I'm just concerned with finding the eigenvalues for the time being.

I understand how to set up the auxiliary equation, and how to solve the general system of the ODE for $\lambda < 1$ and $\lambda = 1$, but I don't understand what the solution does to solve it for $\lambda > 1$.

"For $\lambda > 1$, say $\lambda = 1 + \mu^2, \mu = \sqrt{\lambda-1} > 0$, the general solution is $y(x) = (A\cos(\mu x) + B\sin(\mu x))e^{-x},$ $y(0) = 0 \to A=0,$ then $y(1) = 0 \Rightarrow B = 0,$ or $\sin(\mu) = 0,$ $\mu = n\pi,$ $n = 1, 2, 3...,$ giving the result:

$\lambda_{n} = 1 + n^2\pi^2,$  $\phi_n(x) = e^{-x}\sin(n\pi x),$ $n = 1,2,3,...,$"

(It then checks orthogonality)

I don't understand why it substitutes $\mu$. I thought when dealing with complex roots, you need it to be in form $m = p \pm qi$, to substitute into $y = e^{px}(C_{1}\cos(qx)+C_{2}\sin(qx))$. I've thought about it for a bit, but the link isn't clear yet.

Comment: when $\lambda > 1$, $\mu = \sqrt{\lambda - 1}$ is a real number.

Comment: And the $\lambda-1$ falls out of completing the square: $x^2+2x+\lambda=(x+1)^2+\lambda-1$ which you then identify as $(x+1)^2+\mu^2$. (But it is the same to think about it with the quadratic formula instead. )

Comment: Can you check your boundary conditions, you are actually using $y(0)=y(1)=0$.

Comment: The eigenfunctions themselves have to be defined for the homogeneous problem anyway, so you homogenize the BC (say by looking at $y=1+z$) and then deal with any artificial forcing at the end (in this case you get an artificial forcing of $-\lambda$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thinking and reflection, I think I can better articulate, and answer my question.

So, after finding the auxiliary equation, we can complete the square to find $m$ in terms of $\lambda$.

$m^2+2m+\lambda=0$

...

$m=-1 \pm \sqrt{1-\lambda}$

For $\lambda > 1$, we'll have complex roots. I was previously taught that given complex roots in the form $m=p\pm qi$, we can substitute into this complementary function accordingly:

$y = e^{px}(C_{1}cos(qx) + C_{2}sin(qx))$

However, $m=-1 \pm \sqrt{1-\lambda}$ is not in the form $m = p \pm qi$ (since there isn't explicitly any $i$). That was the crux of my question. What do you do from here?

It's simply a case of equating and solving for $q$.

$qi = \sqrt{1-\lambda}$

$-q^2=1-\lambda$

$q^2 = \lambda - 1$

$q = \pm \sqrt{\lambda - 1}$

So

$m = p \pm q i$

$p = -1$

$q = \sqrt{\lambda - 1}$

Hopefully this makes sense and potentially helps someone in the future :)

(Got no idea why $\mu$ was used instead of $q$ in our notes)